# Consequence of 4'th (Lattice) isomorphism theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I'm curious if this proof is correct.

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a group and $A, B, N$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $N \leq A \leq B$ and $N$ is normal in $G$. Prove the following:
$$
|B:A|=|B/N:A/N|.
$$

**My Proof:**
Consider the map
$$
\begin{align*}
f \colon B/A &\to (B/N)/(A/N) \\
bA & \mapsto (bN)\cdot (A/N)
\end{align*}
$$
$f$ is well defined: Suppose $b_1A=b_2A$. Then $b_2=b_1a'$ for some $a' \in A$. $(bN)(A/N)=\{bN \cdot aN \mid a \in A\}=\{baN \mid a \in A\}$. Thus, $(b_2N)(A/N)=\{b_2aN \mid a \in A\}=\{b_1a'aN \mid a \in A\}$. But since left multiplication by $a'$ is a bijection from $A \to A$, we have $\{b_1a'aN \mid a \in A\}=\{b_1aN\}$. So $f(b_1A)=f(b_2A) \implies f$ is well defined.

$f$ is injective: Suppose $(b_1N)(A/N)=(b_2N)(A/N)$, then $b_1N=b_2N \implies b_2=b_1n$ for some $n \in N$. But since $n \in A$, $b_1A=b_2A$.

$f$ is surjective: If $X \in (B/N)/(A/N)$, then $X=bN(A/N)$ for some $b \in B$, so $f(bA)=X$.

Thus $f$ is a bijection, meaning that the number of cosets of $A$ in $B$ is the same as the number of cosets of $A/N$ in $B/N$. $\square$

**Question:** This fact is apparently a consequence of the 4'th isomorphism theorem. However, I don't use the theorem at all in proving this claim, so I'd be interested in seeing if there is a more succinct proof of this fact.

Comment: Depends how much you fit into the 4th theorem. I've seen it stated as "inclusion preserving, normality preserving, *index preserving* correspondence between the subgroups of $G/N$ and the subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$", in which case it would be an immediate consequence by invoking the index preserving part of the correspondence, after restricting it to $B$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I believe this *is* the proof of the "index preserving" property. The bijection from the proof of the theorem maps a subgroup $A$ containing $N$ to $A/N$, so this is indeed proving that the bijection preserves index.

Comment: again, it depends on what kind of results you might have on hand. The map you give is the homomorphism of the second isomorphism theorem (or third, depending on your nomenclature) when $A$ is normal in $B$. Some people already have that result in hand by the time you get to the 4th. So if someone said “it’s a consequence of the 4th”, then you need to know what went into the 4th isomorphism theorem to see whether they are telling you something new or not.

Comment: Also, note that if the 4th Isomorphism theorem is only stated as index preserving for the index in $G$ (just like it is stated as “normality preserving” only in terms of normality *in $G$*), then this part is not directly part of the theorem, but instead a consequence of the theorem when you restrict look at $B$ instead of $G$.